# Haskell: What is immutable data?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

in most articles about Haskell you'll find a statement like "Data in Haskell is immutable". I don't quite understand why. For example:

```
let a = 123
let a = 456
```

in the main method works. I just changed the data of `a` from `123` to `456`. What am I missing? It's probably a stupid mistake in my train of thought :/

Have a good day!

Comment: You didn’t change the value of `a`; you made a new thing also named `a`. When compiling, the name that appears last is the one that’s selected.

Comment: Ah alright. So I guess, that something like `let a = 3` (newline) `a = a *2` is not allowed?

Comment: Right. Your example would be like doing `let b = a * 2`. (Which works fine for some purposes, of course.)

Comment: Alright, thank you for your answer, got it!

Comment: You shouldn't think of it as the last one, but rather the innermost one. `let a = a * 2` is perfectly legal, but won't do what you expect. Try it and see!

Comment: in GHCi, `a <- return (a*2)` at the prompt OTOH is also legal, and does do what would be expected of it to be doing. *or seem like it does.* :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually, `a` hasn't changed. Try this in `ghci` to see:

```
> a = 123
> action = print a
> a = 456
> action
123
```

Compare with a language that has mutable variables, e.g. python:

```
>>> a = 123
>>> def action(): print a
... 
>>> a = 456
>>> action()
456
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Getting started with functional programming does not seem to be that easy like OOP :D

Comment: @DDerTyp It's a matter of brain "imprinting". If one were exposed to pure FP first, OOP would probably seem harder.

Comment: @DDerTyp, I want to point out that the above is *very* uncommon in haskell, in case this answer is making you think this is working with immutability is like.  We almost never call two things by the same name in overlapping scopes like this.

Comment: @luqui true, except when fiddling around in GHCi/IHaskell. There I often “overwrite” variables. But the old, shadowed values are then not understood as parts of the program flow, but merely as obsolete/erroneous implementations of the same value.