# Reassignment in ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci

Is it possible to reassign the same variable in ghci ? Of course this isn't possible in normal Haskell (at least without something like an IORef), but I was curious because the `it` variable in ghci that you get by enabling the `:m` option. With that enabled I get an experience where `it` is effectively reassignable by *not* binding the next expression to anything, e.g.

```
λ> 1 + 1
2
it :: Num a => a
λ> it
2
it :: Num a => a
λ> it + 1
3
it :: Num a => a
λ> it
3
it :: Num a => a
```

Is there a way to realize the same effect for an arbitrary named variable, not just the special `it` ?

Comment: No it is not reassigning, you simply define a *second* more locally scoped variable `it`.

Comment: See also [What is immutable data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44406434/791604).

Comment: Under ghci, the expression `x <- return (x+1)` seems to do what you would expect.

Comment: @jpmarinier  but only *seems to*. :) it's still shadowing, just in one line of code instead of two, as seen e.g. here: [how to increment a variable in functional programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11923567/849891).

Answer (score 5):

Each new line in GHCi enters new, nested scope. Consider

```
> x = 1
> x
1
> foo y = x + y
> foo 41
42
> x = 7                 -- new x
> x
7
> bar y = x + y         -- refers to new x
> bar 41
48
> foo 41                -- still refers to the same old x binding
42
```

Second binding of `x` defines *new* same-named variable.

Naturally, it *shadows* the previous binding for that name, making it inaccessible in itself. Any other entity (like `foo`) which referenced it before though, will continue to hold *that* reference, no matter the shadowing for the *newer*, nested environments.

This follows the principle of immutability of values in Haskell: the `foo` remains the same.

One caveat:

```
> :{
  x = 1
  foo y = x + y
  x = 7                   -- error: conflicting definition
  bar y = x + y
  :}
```

causes an error, because lines entered in multiline mode belong to the same scope.

In other words the answer to your question is *no*, it would break the fundamental purity properties of Haskell.

`it` is not reassigned either, it is defined anew in each new nested environment, whenever there is any output, being bound to the output value:

```
> x
7
> it
7
> it_2                       -- made a typo

error: Not in scope: `it_2'
> it+2                       -- no previous output, same `it` in effect
9
> it+2                       -- most recent `it` is 9
11
```

---

So you can always shadow your variable and create a new binding with the same name, but you can't change the old binding, because it is a part of history now, and *the past* can not be changed, by definition. It *already happened*.

<sub>Or you could create your own Haskell interpreter where you'd give a user an ability to "change" an old binding, but what would really happen is that a new copy of the interpreter would be spawned even "playing" all the recorded user actions at the prompt -- new definitions and all -- from that point on. Then the user would end up with a changed copy which would be oblivious to the existence of the first one. You could even kill the original at that point. Could this be considered as user having changed the past? *The user's* past hasn't changed, their time goes forward. The *new copy's* past was always what it is now, as far as *it* is concerned. The older original (copy?) is gone... A question to ponder.</sub>